# dynamically append element to div and set css style

Tags: jquery, css

```
Id='a';      
linkId   = '#dialog_link' + Id;

htmlCode = '<p><a href="#" id="' + linkId + '" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span></span>Open Window</a></p>';        
$('#WindowsContainer').append(htmlCode);

$(linkId).css('padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;text-decoration: none;position: relative;');
$(linkId + ' span.ui-icon').css('margin: 0 5px 0 0;position: absolute;left: .2em;top: 50%;margin-top: -8px;');
```

Last two lines didn't affect style of a with id# "dialog_linka".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(linkId).css({ 
    padding: ".4em 1em .4em 20px",
    "text-decoration": "none",
    position: "relative"
});
```

You might want to re-read [the API](http://api.jquery.com/css/) and check what kind of values `$.css()` accepts.

EDIT: If it doesn't work, it's because you haven't created the HTML correctly:

```
htmlCode = '<p><a href="#" id="' + linkId + '" ...'
```

because `linkId` is `"#dialog_linka"`, the id attribute is `id="#dialog_linka"`, when it should be `dialog_linka` (without the hash).

Also, you don't have any element with class `.ui-icon`, at least in the example code.

See http://jsfiddle.net/YDYA6/ for a demo.

Comment: sorry,didn't work, Only work if element predefined in html but if element created by js (NOT WORKED) ...Thanks

Comment: That's because you give the element an invalid id. See the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks first line is working successfull, but the second style $(linkId + ' span.ui-icon') not working where ui-icon class is defined(i am sure for that). Many Thanks Juhana

Comment: Please can you check [dialog-dynamic.html](http://www.4shared.com/file/ec-10zxq/dialog-dynamic.html)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not going to download a .rar. Please make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or use pastebin or something like that.

Comment: i tried to use fiddle but, the problem how to include all JQuery-Ui library that contain many files(css + js + images)

Comment: Just show the HTML and the line that you use to style it. You don't have to put the *entire* page in, just the part that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: [http://osip.netii.net/dialog-dynamic.html](http://osip.netii.net/dialog-dynamic.html)

Comment: The `ui-icon` class is *not* defined in dynamically created links. You're just making an empty `<span></span>`.

Answer (score 3):

Create the element from jquery with the styles set.

```
var id = 2;
var link = $('<a/>',{
   id:'dialog_link' + id,
   class: 'ui-state-default ui-corner-all',
   text: 'Open Window',
   css:{
     padding: '.4em 1em .4em 20px',
     'text-decoration': 'none',
     position: 'relative'
   }
})
```

**Demo** 
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YDYA6/29/)

**References**
 - [Creating element from jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-ownerDocument)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your css arguments as a map of property-value pairs -

```
$(linkId).css({'padding': '.4em 1em .4em 20px','text-decoration': 'none;position: relative'});
```

See the docs here - http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

You are using [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function wrong.

It should be:

```
$(linkId).css({
    'padding': '.4em 1em .4em 20px',
    'text-decoration': 'none',
    'position': 'relative'
});
```

Comment: sorry,didn't work, Only work if element predefined in html but if element created by js (NOT WORKED) ...Thanks

Comment: Thats because you set the id as '#dialog_link' + Id, while html id element cant start with hash sign, it should be 'dialog_link' + Id instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.You can add style attribute instead of using .css function.

```
Id='a';      
linkId   = 'dialog_link' + Id;

htmlCode = '<p><a href="#" id="' + linkId + '" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon"></span>Open Window</a></p>';        
$('#WindowsContainer').append(htmlCode);

$("#"+linkId).attr("style",'padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;text-decoration: none;position: relative;');
$(linkId + ' span.ui-icon').attr("style",'margin: 0 5px 0 0;position: absolute;left: .2em;top: 50%;margin-top: -8px;');
```